# List the cartesian product of the list with itself

Tags: algorithm, function, clojure

```
(defn slist-cartesian [lst] 
  (slist-iter
   lst
   (fn [x]
     (slist-iter
      lst
      (fn [y]
        (println x y))))))
```

So i have an entire code to explain but this part doesn't make sense to me, can someone please explain it to me ? I know list-iter is used when you'd like to see something done with each element of the list but i have trouble following the path here.

Comment: "doesn't make sense to me" is a very broad question. Also add the `slist-iter` source (it most likely is an eager `map`) and anything else, that is not from core -- or if this code from a public place, share a link.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that `slist-iter` does what you explained as `list-iter` behaviour, which is "'used' when you'd like to see something done with each element of the list"...

Now, I'm going to present you another way to do the cartesian product using Clojure core functions, so I can point you the key element that could be confusing you...

```clj
(defn slist-cartesian [lst]
  (doseq [x lst
        y lst]
    (println x y)))
```

That is what `doseq` does. You can read it something like *for each x in lst, and for each y in lst, print x and y*.

Now, the key part here is that you are repeating `lst` both for `x` and `y`. That way we get the Cartesian product of `lst` with `lst`.

That is exactly what the code you show is doing. It is using `lst` as the list to be processed by both of the `slist-iter` calls.

Understand that it is **needed** to process the list each time from the beginning, to get what you are asking: The Cartesian product.

And now understand that you **can** do it both with the **doseq** expression and within the **slist-iter** functions.

Probably you need to understand **why** you **can** do it in the **slist-iter** form.

It is possible because `fn` creates a function and also that function is a [Closure](https://www.braveclojure.com/do-things/#Returning_Functions) "which means that 'it' can access all the variables that were in scope when the function was created".

That means that that function `slist-cartesian` is creating with `fn` when calling the first `slist-iter`, has access to the parameter `lst`. Let's refer to that function as the anonymous one.

That anonymous function will be called again each time the first `slist-iter` begins to process a new element of `lst`, but `lst` is going to be the same `slist-cartesian` received and used when the later created the former.

I hope this answered your question.

---

If you still want to think and dig more in the subject, there is another way to think about this is by constructing the function one step at a time.

So in your own words ...

```clj
(defn slist-cartesian [lst]
  (slist-iter 
   lst ;; The list with the elements
   ,,, ;; The thing to be done to the elements to the list
   ))
```

The *thing to be done* is a **function** that receive **1** parameter. That function will be called passing as an argument an element of the list, one element at a time for all the elements in the list.

If we make `println` the function, it will call it many times, one per element of the list, with such element as argument. Which means that it would print the whole list, one item at a time:

```
(defn slist-cartesian [lst]
  (slist-iter 
   lst
   println
   ))

(slist-cartesian '(1 2 3))
;; 1
;; 2
;; 3
```

What happens when you need to add more information to what is printed? You need a more complex function than simply `println`.

Let's create a function that will prefix a text to each item on the list and print them. Let's prefix the text `"number: "`. Because we have `slist-iter` we just only need to solve the problem of prefixing the text to a single number, with a function with only one parameter so it can be used by `slist-iter` and so solving the problem for all elements in the list. Let's make that solution a function:

```clj
(defn prefix-text-number-and-print [x]
  (println "number: " x))
```

And now let's use it to build a function that prefix `"number: "` to all elements of a list and print them. Let's call that function `prefix-text-number-to-each`:

```clj
(defn prefix-text-number-to-each [lst]
  (slist-iter
   lst
   prefix-text-number-and-print))

(prefix-text-number-to-each '(1 2 3))
;; number: 1
;; number: 2
;; number: 3
```

Cool. But what happen if we need to change the text of the prefix? That means that the function `prefix-text-number-and-print` needs to be generalized by adding a parameter for such prefix. But that will make that function useless for `slist-iter`. What then?

What we will do is to create the generalized function, and then somehow derive from it an specialized function we need on the precise moment.

```
(defn prefix-text-and-print [prefix, x] ;; Generalized function
  (println prefix x))
```

So for the soon to be function `prefix-text-to-each`, we would do something like:

```clj
(defn prefix-text-to-each [prefix, x]
  (slist-iter
   lst
   (somehow-derive-a-function prefix-text-and-print prefix))) ;; ATTENTION
```

There are many ways to create functions on the spot. You already used one tool for that in the code you show. You are using the function `fn` to build a function in place. Another way to do it is with the function `partial`. Let's explore the `partial` option first.

For that, I will do to `prefix-text-and-print` the opposite of what I did to `prefix-text-number-and-print`. I will specialize it. I will define `prefix-text-number-and-print` in terms of `prefix-text-and-print`. First by hand, and then by using `partial`:

```clj
;; By hand
(defn prefix-text-number-and-print [x]
  (prefix-text-and-print "number: " x))

;; Using partial
(def prefix-text-number-and-print
  (partial prefix-text-and-print "number: "))
```

Both definitions produce the same result: a function. Note the last one uses `def` instead of `defn`.

The definition using partial is simple a `def`. So it is simply defining `prefix-text-number-and-print` with whatever value is created by the call to `partial`.

[partial](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/partial) creates a function. That new function will simply call the first parameter received by partial (in this case `prefix-text-and-print`) with the rest of the arguments partial received as arguments (in this case only "number: ") followed by the arguments the function itself receives.

Try it, it doesn't matter what version you used, the result will be the same:

```clj
(prefix-text-number-and-print 123)
;; number: 123
```

You could have done it in place of the call, with the same result

```clj
((partial prefix-text-and-print "number: ") 123)
;; number: 123
```

Now that you now how to use `partial`, let's use it to build a generalized function `prefix-text-to-each`

```clj
(defn prefix-text-to-each [prefix, lst]
  (slist-iter
   lst
   (partial prefix-text-and-print prefix))) ;; ATTENTION
```

Let's try it:

```clj
(prefix-text-to-each "hola: " '(1 2 3)
;; hola: 1
;; hola: 2
;; hola: 3
```

Now we could think on making a function that combines not a text, but a list, with each element of another list. Again, we begin with combining the thing (a list) to a single element:

```clj
(def sufix-list-and-print [a-lst x] ;; Yeap, for practical reasons, let's suffix the thing (the list) instead of prefixing.
  (slist-iter
   a-lst
   (partial prefix-text-and-print x ;; we are reusing this function, why not?
            )))

(sufix-list-and-print '(1 2 3) 88)
;; 88 1
;; 88 2
;; 88 3
```

With that function, we can now create the function that combines 2 lists:

```
(def print-2-lsts-combined [a-lst b-lst]
  (slist-iter
   b-lst
   (partial prefix-list-and-print a-lst)))
```

Let's try that:

```
(print-2-lsts-combined '(1 2 3) '(10 20 30))
;; 1 10
;; 1 20
;; 1 30
;; 2 10
;; 2 20
;; 2 30
;; 3 10
;; 3 20
;; 3 30
```

It happens that if the 2 lists are the same, you will have the Cartesian product. So you can define the Cartesian product in terms of this function:

```clj
(defn slist-cartesian [lst]
  (print-2-lst-combined lst lst))
```

Or by itself in a similar way to the `print-2-lst-combined` function, which resembles the code you show originally:

```clj
(def slist-cartesian [lst]
  (slist-iter
   lst
   (partial prefix-list-and-print lst) ;; ATENTION
   ))
```

Now, the original code uses `fn` instead of `partial`. `fn` and `partial` have the same job: to create a function.

Do you see it?

The problem in the list commented with `ATTENTION` was to give somehow the list `lst` to a function that receives only 1 parameter and you couldn't use that parameter for such purpose.

So the solution with `partial` was to derive such function.

The solution with `fn` was to express that function in place, and "say" the word `lst` when needed, because it could due to it being a Closure, as explained before. That is an [anonymous function](https://clojure.org/guides/learn/functions#_anonymous_functions) and I invite you to read more about it.

Comment: `for` is the wrong function here. For side effects you want `doseq`.

Comment: You are right. It is better to do it with doseq. The for technically works if you realize the seq. But you have to make it happen. You are right. I'm changing it to doseq.